# Regex to retrieve after first slash and next slash only

Tags: regex, bash, shell

If I have a web url with following https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git

How can I retrieve only between the first and second slash "myorg" using regex ?

I have looked up few and only found the how to retrieve last piece using `| sed 's#.*/##'`

Comment: Try this: `sed 's#[^/]*//[^/]*/\([^/]*\).*#\1#' <<< 'https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git'`. Btw, between the first and second slash is the null string. You probably want to get between second and third slash.

Comment: This worked for me straight away thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a regex but very simple

```
echo https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git | awk -F\/ '{print $4}'
```

Slightly more flexible as it get's the next to last field:

```
echo https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git | awk -F\/ '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash's builtin Regex engine:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
url='https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git'

if [[ $url =~ github.com/([^/]+)/ ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Using POSIX-shell grammar variable expansion:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

url='https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git'
t="${url#*github.com/}"
org="${t%%/*}"
printf '%s\n' "$org"
```

Answer (score 0):

You, my friend, can use lookaheads e lookbehinds

```
(?<=\.com\/).+(?=\/)
```

this code it will get everything between slashs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).